# How can you return null from orElse within Iterable.firstWhere with null-safety enabled?

Tags: flutter, dart

Prior to null-safe dart, the following was valid syntax:

```dart
final list = [1, 2, 3];
final x = list.firstWhere((element) => element > 3, orElse: () => null);

if (x == null) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

Now, `firstWhere` requires `orElse` to return an `int`, opposed to an `int?`, therefore I cannot return null.

How can I return null from `orElse`?

Comment: What sense to return `null` instead of -1, for example?

Comment: @BambinoUA When working with more complex types. Maybe this was too simple an example.

Comment: FYI, this is covered in the Dart null-safety FAQ: https://dart.dev/null-safety/faq#the-iterablefirstwhere-method-no-longer-accepts-orelse---null

Comment: You want to do this in the case of e.g setting an initial value in a dropdown. You might search a list for a specific id, but if that id isn't found, you just want to return back null since a dropdown may not have a selected item

Answer (score 73, accepted):

A handy function, `firstWhereOrNull`, solves this exact problem.

Import [`package:collection`](https://pub.dev/packages/collection) which includes extension methods on `Iterable`.

```dart
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';

final list = [1, 2, 3];
final x = list.firstWhereOrNull((element) => element > 3);

if (x == null) {
  // do stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need external package for this instead you can use try/catch

```
int? x;
try {
  x = list.firstWhere((element) => element > 3);
} catch(e) {
  x = null;
}
```

Comment: collection is not an external package, it's just not bundled with the fundamental flutter import.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @Alex Hartfords answer, and for anyone who doesn't want to import a full package just for this functionality, this is the actual implementation for `firstWhereOrNull` from the `collection` package that you can add to your app.

```
extension FirstWhereExt<T> on List<T> {
  /// The first element satisfying [test], or `null` if there are none.
  T? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(T element) test) {
    for (final element in this) {
      if (test(element)) return element;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work, and it's a better solution:

```dart
extension IterableExtensions<T> on Iterable<T> {
  T? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(T element) comparator) {
    try {
      return firstWhere(comparator);
    } on StateError catch (_) {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit late but i came up with this:

```
typedef FirstWhereClosure = bool Function(dynamic);

extension FirstWhere on List {
  dynamic frstWhere(FirstWhereClosure closure) {
    int index = this.indexWhere(closure);

    if (index != -1) {
      return this[index];
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Example use:

```
class Test{
  String name;
  int code;
  
  Test(code, this.name);
}

Test? test = list.frstWhere(t)=> t.code==123);
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is that you set a *nullable* type to the list.

Instead of just `[1, 2, 3]`, you write `<int?>[1, 2, 3]`, allowing it to be *nullable*.

```dart
void main() {
  final list = <int?>[1, 2, 3];
  final x = list.firstWhere(
      (element) => element != null ? (element > 3) : false,
      orElse: () => null);

  print(x);
}
```